# Pre-load R packages in R Services

Tags: sql-server

I have an R script that calculates prediction that's run on R Services via a stored proc.  Running the stored proc takes ~3s but the majority of the time is from loading R packages (~2.5s)

`library(PACKAGE)`

Is there a way to pre-load these packages when executing the stored proc so that the execution time gets cut to just calculating the predicted value.